# How to automate entering data from a database into a website's html & javascript user interface?

Tags: javascript, html, database, browser-automation

I am a volunteer coordinator for a not-for-profit with some basic experience using Python. I'm willing to put in <8 hours of learning for my current project (otherwise, I'll do it manually). I'm running OSX 10.6. I might be able to get help from one of my volunteers :)

I have an excel spreadsheet of information about my volunteers, and I'm trying to automate the task of updating specific fields in my web-based volunteer management software from the data in entries from my spreadsheet.
I've read responses to related questions, but none seem to include the external excel database. Also, I understand that I may be able to bypass the user-interface (by building my own html connection to the software's website).

Please suggest the simplest, and alternatively, the most flexible tool I might use for this task. What information would I need about the remote software? Is there a better format than excel for my database? Any clarifying questions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP is probably the most common way people do this but considering your 8 hour limit and affinity for spreadsheets, you can check out http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/
for a way to make use of an online spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks GroovyDotCom! I will definitely look into Google spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try online form/survey services. [Jotforms](http://www.jotform.com/pricing/) have a good free plan that might fit your needs.